# Cascade trigger not working

Tags: postgresql, triggers, cascade

Hei guys. The point is simple. I have some tables called PERSONS, STUDENTS, EMPLOYEES. And IDPERSON = idstudent, idperson = idemployee. SO far so good.

Im trying to get make a delete cascade trigger that, whenever I delete a PERSON,  it deletes the row in table PERSONS and it deletes depending if that person was putten in table STUDENTS or EMPLOYEES.

Because in table PERSONS i find only (Name, IDPERSON, Telephone, Email, etc) and in Student/Emplyee I find more technical details, such as: ScheduleEmployee, IdAccomodationStudent, etc. Hope u got it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION stergereStudenti () RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
DELETE FROM persoane WHERE idpersoana = OLD.idpersoana;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trgStergereStudenti BEFORE DELETE ON TABLE studenti
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE stergereStudenti();
```

For some reason it doesnt work. I looked into old stackoverflow posts and I got the trigger above and addapted on my Database. But is not working.. Please help :(

Comment: Shouldn't your trigger be on 'before delete on table persoane'?

Comment: Hmm.. dont think so..

Comment: You say that you want to delete an entry from the PERSON table and have the associated STUDENT or EMPLOYEE deleted as well. But what your trigger does is when a STUDENT is deleted, it deletes the associated PERSON. What statement are you actually executing?

Answer (score 0):

Triggers look like the wrong tool for the job. Instead, you could use a foreign key with the `on delete cascade` option:

```
ALTER TABLE student 
ADD CONSTRAINT student_fk
FOREIGN KEY(idpersoana) 
REFERENCES person(idpersoana) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Hmm.. in my project I am supposed to use a trigger.. If you have any idea about how that trigger should look like, would be great, if not, I.ll alter the table.